# spark-cassandra-connector: add column on the fly

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

The following cqlsh command adds a column to an already existing cassandra table.

```
cqlsh:demodb> ALTER TABLE users ADD coupon_code varchar;
```

How would I do the same with the scala spark-cassandra-connector?

I am not seeing reference in the documents.

ALSO: Is there a scaladoc for `com.datastax.spark.connector`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `withSessionDo` method of the `CassandraConnector`, like this:

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector

CassandraConnector(conf).withSessionDo { session =>
   session.execute("ALTER TABLE users ADD coupon_code varchar;")
}
```

See [more examples](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/1_connecting.md) in documentation for Spark Cassandra connector...

Comment: I am doing NLP...so every time a new word shows up, it will create a new column. In "immature" tan;es, this could be frequent

Comment: I don't think that this is good idea, especially if modification could happen from multiple threads... I would recommend to change table schema to accommodate new words as part of existing schema, for example, make the `word` a clustering column before any other "value columns"